# Create Event (Checked/Unchecked) for ComboBox inside an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm pretty new to WPF & MVVM, I'm having 3 CheckBox items on the panel, I need that each time when the user click one of them a method will be called. This method should check the status of each one of the 3 CheckBox (which one of them is 'Checked', and which of them is 'Unchecked') and use this information for displaying some text on a TextBlock. For example it will display "A" if all the 3 are Checked, and "B" if all of them are Unchecked.

I got little complicated with this, and hope that you can help me with this.

**Here is the XAML code:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckBoxCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" >
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <TextBlock>Result Here</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

**Here is the code behind:**

```
public class CheckBoxValue
{
    bool _theValue;

    public bool theValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _theValue;
        }

        set
        {
            _theValue = value;
        }
    }
}

public class myViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxValue> CheckBoxCollection { get; set; }

    public myViewModel( Some Parameters.... )
    {
        CheckBoxCollection = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxValue>();

        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { theValue = false });
        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { theValue = false });
        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { theValue = false });

        base.RaisePropertyChanged( () => CheckBoxCollection );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go a step further and define a reusable ViewModel for all types of "Selectable" things:

```
public class Selectable<T>: ViewModelBase //ViewModelBase should Implement NotifyPropertyChanged.
{
    private T _model;
    public T Model 
    {   get { return _model; }
        set 
        {
            _model = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("Model");
        }
    }

    public Action OnIsSelectedChanged;

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("IsSelected");

            if (OnIsSelectedChanged != null)
                OnIsSelectedChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

See how I'm using a [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) that will be called when `IsSelected` is changed, so that you can handle the selection change at the ViewModel level:

```
public class CheckBoxValue: Selectable<string>
{
   //.. no need for any special stuff here
}

public class myViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxValue> CheckBoxCollection { get; set; }

    public myViewModel( Some Parameters.... )
    {
        CheckBoxCollection = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxValue>();

        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { Model = "CheckBox1" });
        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { Model = "CheckBox2" });
        CheckBoxCollection.Add(new CheckBoxValue { Model = "CheckBox3" });
        //Setting IsSelected to false is redundant because bools default to false, so I removed that.

        //Calling NotifyPropertyChange in the constructor is also redundant because the object is just being constructed, therefore WPF did not even read the initial values from it yet.

       //Now, here we handle the Selection change:
       foreach (var item in CheckBoxCollection)
           item.OnIsSelectedChanged = OnCheckBoxSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCheckBoxSelectionChanged()
    {
       //... etc    
    }
```

XAML:

```
<!-- Two way binding to the ItemsSource property is redundant, it doesn't make sense. -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckBoxCollection}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- CheckBox.IsChecked BindsToWayByDefault, so it is also redundant
                 See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault(v=vs.110).aspx -->

            <!-- Also see how I'm adding content to the CheckBox here -->

            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Model}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

}

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast answer! I'm checking it (why can't I reply in a large edit box, and why does it automatically sending my message when I click 'Enter'? that's strange)

Comment: Why can't I see my question on the main forum page even when I'm refreshing the page? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: HighCore, actually why do I need the "T Model" property? I disabled it, and I changed "Model = "CheckBox1"" to "IsSelected = false", and in the xaml I changed to "<CheckBox Content="{Binding IsSelected}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>" ... and it works perfectly, I get to the OnCheckBoxSelectionChanged() method and able to check the status of each CheckBox in the list :-)

Comment: @John my solution is more scalable, because it enables you to use it not only for this CheckBox case, but also for any type of selectable content. And is also richer in features, since having a `T` Model, you can actually use it to display, for instance, `Person` objects in a `ListBox` or things like that. As I told you before, setting `IsSelected` to `false` is redundant because that is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I probably changed this too much but this may be the simpler way of doing it.

```
<StackPanel>
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxValue1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxValue2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxValue3, Mode=TwoWay}" />


 <TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
   <Binding Path="StringValue" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
  </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>





#region properties
    string stringValue;
    public StringValue
    {
    get {return stringValue;}
    set 
    {
     stringValue = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("StringValue");
    }

    }
    bool checkBoxValue1;
    public bool CheckBoxValue1
    {
        get{ return checkBoxValue1; }
        set
        {
             checkBoxValue1= value;
             ChangedValue();
        }
    }
    bool checkBoxValue2;
    public bool CheckBoxValue2
    {
        get{ return checkBoxValue2; }
        set
        {
             checkBoxValue2 = value;
             ChangedValue();
        }
    }
    bool checkBoxValue3;
    public bool CheckBoxValue3
    {
        get{ return checkBoxValue3; }
        set
        {
             checkBoxValue3 = value;
             ChangedValue();
        }
    }
#endregion

public class myViewModel : ViewModelBase
{


    public myViewModel( Some Parameters.... )
    {
        checkBoxValue1 = false;
        checkBoxValue2 = false;
        checkBoxValue3 = false;
        StringValue = b;

    }
    public void ChangedValue()
    {
      if (checkBoxValue1 && checkBoxValue2 && checkBoxValue3)
      {
          StringValue = a
      }
      else
      {
          StringValue = b
      }
    }
}
```

Sorry this is kind of thrown together but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I must create the CheckBox items in my code behind, i showed here only 3 CheckBox items just for the simplicity, but in my original code (which I haven't showed here) I'm creating them inside a loop, and their quantity can be changed...)